# fully connection algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I have encoutered an algorithm question:

**Fully Connection**

Given *n* cities which spreads along a line, let *X<sub>i</sub>* be the position of city *i* and *P<sub>i</sub>* be its population.

Now we begin to lay cables between every two of the cities based on their distance and population. Given two cities *i* and *j*, the cost to lay cable between them is |*X<sub>i</sub>*-*X<sub>j</sub>*|*max(*P<sub>i</sub>*,*P<sub>j</sub>*). How much does it cost to lay all the cables?

For example, given:

```
i   Xi   Pi
-   --  --
1   1   4
2   2   5
3   3   6
```

Then the total cost can be calculated as:

```
i  j  |Xi-Xj|  max(Pi, Pj)  Segment Cost
-  -  ------  -----------  ------------
1  2    1        5              5
2  3    1        6              6
1  3    2        6             12
```

So that the total cost is 5+6+12 = 23.

While this can clearly be done in O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) time, can it be done in asymptotically less time?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of faster solution. If I am not wrong it goes to O(n*logn). Now let's first sort all the cities according to Pi. This is O(n* log n). Then we start processing the cities in increasing order of Pi. the reason being - you always know you have max (Pi, Pj) = Pi in this case. We only want to add all the segments that come from relations with Pi. Those that will connect with larger indexes will be counted when they will be processed.

Now the thing I was able to think of was to use several index trees in order to reduce the complexity of the algorithm. First index tree is counting the number of nodes and can process queries of the kind: how many nodes are to the right of xi in logarithmic time. Lets call this number NR. The second index tree can process queries of the kind: what is the sum of distances from all the points to the right of a given x. The distances are counted towards a fixed point that is guaranteed to be to the right of the rightmost point, lets call its x XR.Lets call this number SUMD. Then the sum of the distances to all points to the right of our point can be found that way: NR * dist(Xi, XR)  - SUMD. Then all these contribute (NR * dist(Xi, XR)  - SUMD) *Pi to the result. The same for the left points and you get the answer. After you process the ith point you add it to the index trees and can go on.

**Edit**: Here is one article about Biary index trees: http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees

Comment: thank u very much.i have also considered to add cities in increasing order of Pi and calculate the cable cost by characters of cities:the number of cities to the left of it,the distances to the leftmost city,the number of cities to the right of it,the distances to the rightmost city.However i found the update requires O(n),so i cannot figure it out.Now i see how it works using BIT, thank u again

Comment: I am glad to be of service. I would really appreciate if you upvote and mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the check next to the upvote counter if I really helped you and my solution worked. This mark means for future readers that this is real solution and works. I can see you are new to Stackoverflow, but I should warn you that if you don't accept any answers to your questions the community will stop answering your questions at some point.

Answer (score 0):

This is the direct connections problem from [codesprint 2](http://cs2.interviewstreet.com/recruit/challenges/).

They will be posting worked solutions to all problems within a week on their website.

(They have said "Now that the contest is over, we're totally cool with everyone discussing their solutions to the problems.")